# How do I merge rows of maps into one map in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a dataframe:

```
df
.groupBy($"letters")
.agg(collect_list($"numbers").as("numbers"))
.select(map($"letters",$"numbers").as("data"))
.agg(collect_list($"data").as("data"))
.select(to_json($"data").as("output"))
.show(false)

+------------------------------------------+
|output                                    |
+------------------------------------------+
|[{"abc":["123","456"]},{"def":["123"]}]   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

How can I get it into this format?

```
+------------------------------------------+
|output                                    |
+------------------------------------------+
|{"abc":["123","456"],"def":["123"]}       |
+------------------------------------------+
```

So that basically it is one map, with no [] brackets at the ends

In other words, it is currently

```
res34: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [data: array<map<string,array<string>>>]
```

Comment: A map is represented by a `key` and `value`; your example is an array of `string` where the containing is `abc -> [123, 456]`, we can work this around but you will not have a solution for maps but for arrays of strings. Something similar about maps would look like: `[{abc -> [123, 456]}]`. So you can either edit your post or we can do a workaround for your example (through array operations).

Comment: thanks, understood. I have updated to work with maps and I think I am closer now. Any way you could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset is this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|output                               |
+-------------------------------------+
|[{abc -> [123, 456]}, {def -> [123]}]|
+-------------------------------------+
```

That has been created through:

```scala
var ds = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  List(Map("abc" -> Array("123", "456")), Map("def" -> Array("123"))),
)).toDF("output")
```

We get:

```
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------------------+
|output                               |keys      |values             |map                              |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------------------+
|[{abc -> [123, 456]}, {def -> [123]}]|[abc, def]|[[123, 456], [123]]|{abc -> [123, 456], def -> [123]}|
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Through:

```scala
ds = ds
  .withColumn("keys", expr("transform(output, x -> map_keys(x)[0])"))
  .withColumn("values", expr("transform(output, x -> flatten(map_values(x)))"))
  .withColumn("map", map_from_arrays(col("keys"), col("values")))
```

I could not think of a better solution, the code is also self explanatory so I don't think there is a need for comments, hope it works for you, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try pyspark.sql.functions.map_concat

Comment: Please extend your answer with some solution source code and explanation describing how it solves the problem.